# Does NetBeans play nice with Eclipse projects and vice-versa?

Tags: eclipse, ide, netbeans

I recently switched from Eclipse to NetBeans (although I don't have any current Eclipse projects lying around that I have easy access to), but a lot of people that I work with (and even my department at school) use Eclipse as their primary IDE.

Are there any known catches to using NetBeans with projects made by others in Eclipse? How about things that might interfere with someone using Eclipse from importing one of my projects?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eclipse projects are not compatible with Netbeans one.

Having said so, you can easily have both project configurations on the same folder (or SCM system). So you could easily integrate them. That is especially true if you have plain Java projects (not Java EE). With Java EE things are a little bit more complicated.

Answer (score 2):

I work in a department that uses both Eclipse and Netbeans successfully.  Maven basically made this possible and fairly easy.  If you are using ant I imagine there is some way to get Netbeans to grok the project.  If you are using some other build tool you will have to set up a separate build file in ant or maven for the Netbeans users...